# Javascript prototype

Tags: javascript

Using a constructor function and a prototype, I want the Grade function to output a number grade into a letter grade.

```
function Grade(name, grade)  {
      this.name = name;
    }

   Grade.prototype.grade = function(){
        if(grade >= 90){return "A"}
        else if (grade <90 && grade >=80){return "B"}
        else if(grade <80 && grade >= 70) {return "C"}
        else {return "fail"}
      };
var sally = new Grade("Sally", 72);
 console.log(sally.grade());
    console.log(sally.name);
```

Comment: You never save the passed `grade` value anywhere so your `grade` function cannot use a variable named `grade` that hasnt been defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the grade you pass in to the constructor as well as any other properties you want available to the newly created object, not just the name. And change the name of the `grade` method to `getGrade` or any other name you'd like to avoid it getting shadowed by the property.

```
function Grade(name, grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}

Grade.prototype.getGrade = function() {
    if(this.grade >= 90){return "A"}
    else if (this.grade <90 && this.grade >=80){return "B"}
    else if(this.grade <80 && this.grade >= 70) {return "C"}
    else {return "fail"}
}

var sally = new Grade("Sally", 72);
console.log(sally.getGrade());  // C
console.log(sally.name); // Sally
```

Comment: You can get rid of parts of the `if` statements.  For example, this `else if (this.grade <90 && this.grade >=80){return "B"}` can just be this `else if (this.grade >=80){return "B"}` because the prior line of code already rules out the grade being above 90.

Comment: Answers should contain more than just a code snippet, explain what you have changed and why

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it may be nicer to move the grade boundaries into a separate object:

```
function Grade(name, score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}

Grade.boundaries = [
    [90, "A"],
    [80, "B"],
    [70, "C"]
];

Grade.prototype.grade = function() {
    var boundary = Grade.boundaries.find(function(boundary) {
        return this.score >= boundary[0];
    });

    return boundary ? boundary[1] : "fail";
};

var sally = new Grade("Sally", 72);
console.log(sally.grade()); // C
console.log(sally.name); // Sally
```